# Cant add events for controls in WPF IronPython VS2010

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010, ironpython

I installed VS2010 and IronPython tools. When I start a VB.NET WPFProject everything works fine. But when I start a WPF IronPython project, it creates a button by default which fills all the window, and when you try to add an event to that control or another control dragged from the toolbox, you just cant do it. You double click on them, but the event is never added to the sourcecode. Anyone had this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently we don't have support for double clicking and adding an event handler.  For the time being you'll need to wire it up by hand.  We are going to spend some time on improving the designer experience so that this should eventually work.